# Calling assignment operator on an array

Tags: c++, arrays, assignment-operator

I wonder how this code could work:

```
struct my_array
{
    int r[1000];
};

int main()
{
    my_array foo, bar;
    foo = bar;
}
```

Because the `foo = bar` call will invoke the constructor-provided `operator=` for the class, which will lazily apply it on every members. But arrays don't have an implementation for `operator=`, proof is, this code fails to compile:

```
int main()
{
    int a[1000], b[1000];
    a = b;
}
```

So how come my first code compiles?

Comment: Because `struct`s, like `class`es, do have a default `operator=` that copies each member.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes? This is what I wrote, the default `operator=` is invoked, which will in turn apply `operator=` on every member, my question is: how does this work given arrays don't have `operator=` (i.e. can't be copied)

Comment: The default `operator=` copies each member. It doesn't necessarily call `operator=` on them unless that's the appropriate way to copy them. Why should a `struct` with `int r[2];` copy differently from a `struct `with `int r1, r2;`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I see, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So how come my first code compiles?

The language specification says it has to work, and the compiler implements that behaviour.

The default assignment semantics are specified in clause 28 of **§ 12.8 [class.copy]**. Specifically, the object's data members are assigned one by one. In the case of an array, this the array's elements are assigned one by one.

> The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator for a
>   non-union class X ***performs memberwise copy- /move assignment*** of its
>   subobjects. ...

and

> — if the subobject is an array, ***each element is assigned***, in the manner appropriate to the element type;

(emphasis mine)

---

Note that in your particular example, the first code sample invokes *undefined behaviour* because the elements of `bar` are uninitialized at the moment you read from them here:

```
foo = bar; // UB: bar.r uninitialized
```

You can fix that by suitable initializing `bar`:

```
my_array foo;
my_array bar{};
```

Comment: So the standard specifies the meaning of "copying" an array. I guess the only reason why `operator=` isn't defined for an array is that it would cause a mess when arrays decay into pointers?

Comment: @qdii It is a mess inherited from C. It would be hard to reconcile copy of arrays with pointer decay (and particularly array function parameter adjustment), although I don't see obvious problems with assignment. But it is the way it is and it can't be changed.